# How to submit textbox value when clicked some button to angularjs function?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

What I trying to do, is to submit 2 separate values from 2 textboxes. Each textbox contains a `datetimepicker` using JQuery. How do I submit my 2 textbox value into javascript function using angularjs?

Here is how I create the form :
index.html

```
    <fieldset class="well the-fieldset">
    <h4>Date</h4>
    <form class="form-inline" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">First Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="First_Date" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Last Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Last_date" />
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="selectPOoutStanding(First_Date,Last_Date)" >Process</button> 
    </form>
    </fieldset>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No PO</th>
                <th>Tanggal PO</th>
                <th>Keterangan</th>
                <th>Tanggal Jatuh Tempo</th>
                <th>Divisi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="listPOoutStanding in listPOoutStandings">
                <td>{{listPOoutStanding.id}}</td>
                <td>{{listPOoutStanding.tgl_opj}}</td>
                <td>{{listPOoutStanding.ket}}</td>
                <td>{{listPOoutStanding.tgl_jth_tempo}}</td>
                <td>{{listPOoutStanding.divisi}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my AngularJS controller, i named it "App.js"

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {

    var urlReport = "http://localhost:8080/SpringService/service/laporan/laporanoutstanding";

    $scope.selectPOoutStanding = function selectPOoutStanding(First_Date,Last_Date){
        $http.get(urlReport + "/"+First_Date+"/"+Last_Date)
        .success(function(response){
            alert("heheh");
            $scope.listPOoutStandings = response;
        });
    };
});
```

What I got in my Java Controller is undefined variable when passing the value, here is my java controller :
SpringController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/laporanoutstanding/{first_date}/{last_date}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public List<PoOutstandingList> selectLaporanPOoutstanding(@PathVariable String first_date, @PathVariable String last_date) {  

    List<PoOutstandingList> LaporanPoOutstanding = new ArrayList<PoOutstandingList>();

    try {
        LaporanPoOutstanding = laporanPOoutstanding.findAllPOoutstanding(first_date,last_date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return LaporanPoOutstanding;
}
```

What I got in `@PathVariable` String `first_date` and `@PathVariable` String `last_date` it's undefined when passing via javascript, but when I trigger my JSON service via webbrowser http://localhost:8080/SpringService/service/laporan/laporanoutstanding/2015-08-01/2015-08-29
it works correctly. That means that there is something I miss in my javascript when submiting the 2 values in the textbox. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ng-model in the input controls to get the values in angularjs

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="First_Date" id="First_Date" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Last_date" id="Last_date" />
```

Then inside your controller, you can use `$scope.Last_date` or `$scope.First_date` to refer the values

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for inputText which bind controller value to view.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputName2">First Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="First_Date" ng-model="First_Date"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Last Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Last_date" ng-model="Last_Date" />
</div>
```

Add below two link below `var urlReport` to initialize value of `First_Date` and `Last_Date`.

```
$scope.First_Date = '';
$scope.Last_Date = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a ng-model attrib to your inputs like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="First_Date" class="form-control" id="First_Date" />
```

and for the second

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Last_date" class="form-control" id="Last_date" />
```